# ASP MVC Make Class Namespace Available In All Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, iprincipal

I have the following Permission class. How can I make this available in all views without having to use the following using statement in each view `@using MyApp.Extensions`

```
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace MyApp.Entensions
{
     public class Permissions
     {
         private readonly IPrincipal user;

         public Permissions(IPrincipal user)
         {
             this.user = user;
         }


         public bool CanEditItems
         {
            get { return user.IsInAnyRole("Manager", "Admin"); }
         }

        public bool CanDeleteItems
        {
           get { return user.IsInAnyRole("Admin"); }
        }

        // Other permissions

     }
 }
```

I've tried adding it to the views web.config as follows but I don't get any intellisense when tryin to call something like `@if (User.CanDeleteItems)`

```
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="MyApp.Extensions" />
 </namespaces>
</pages>
```

Comment: Don't you mean @model.user.CanDeleteItems or something like that? Otherwise, what is User in your cshtml file?

Comment: @Peter you've misunderstood. I'm not passing in a model. The class extendd the IPrinciple so User is the currentl logged in user.

Comment: So you're doing a check and rendering the contents of the view based on the boolean outcome of that condition? If so, wouldn't you be better wrapping your content at the layout file level?

Comment: Your code provided does not extend `IPrinciple`.

Comment: Don't forget to mark my answer as accepted if it solves your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add extensions to IPrinciple then you need an extension class, like so

```
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace MyApp.Entensions
{
     public static class Permissions
     {
         public static bool CanEditItems(this IPrinciple user)
         {
            return user.IsInAnyRole("Manager", "Admin"); 
         }

        public static bool CanDeleteItems(this IPrinciple user)
        {
           return user.IsInAnyRole("Admin"); 
        }

        // Other permissions

     }
 }
```

Not that the class is public + static, and the extension methods are public + static and also have "this" before the first parameter.  You will need to change your view to use CanEditItems() as a method instead of a property.

```
if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.CanEditItems()) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks @Kapol, I had indeed :)